# Javascript - Animation only working the first time the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have an animation which is called using onmousedown. I have another function which stops the animation (onmouseup).

The problem is that it only works the first time. By that I mean when I hold the button, it works and then stops when I stop pressing down but if I try to use either of the buttons after that first time nothing happens. It just won't move.

This is my HTML code (index.htm):

```
<html>
<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'></head>
<body>
    <img id='player' src='img/player.png' style='height:64px;'></img>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <button id='moveleft' onmousedown="OnButtonDownl (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpl (this)"><--</button>
        <button id='moveright' onmousedown="OnButtonDownr (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpr (this)">--></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<script type='text/javascript' src='move.js'></script>
```

This is my javascript code (move.js):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("player");
function OnButtonDownl (button) {
var posl = document.getElementById("player").style.left;
window.idl = setInterval(framel, 5);
function framel() {
    posl--;
    elem.style.left = posl + 'px';
}}
function OnButtonUpl (button) {
    clearInterval(idl);
}

var elem = document.getElementById("player");
function OnButtonDownr (button) {
var posr = document.getElementById("player").style.left;
window.idr = setInterval(framer, 5);
function framer() {
    posr++;
    elem.style.left = posr + 'px';
}}
function OnButtonUpr (button) {
    clearInterval(idr);
}
```

Probably not important but here is my css (style.css):

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
position:relative;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#player {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.buttons {
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: could you add a plunkr?

Comment: Does console show anything the second time you try to press the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into 2 issues.

1. When you first get `posl` and `posr`, you're getting an empty string that JS is coercing to `0`.
2. The `--` and `++` won't work after you append the `px` (thus making `posl` and `posr` into `string` values)

Your `posl--` (and `posr++`) *can* increment that coerced `0`. That's why it works the first time through. The next time you `mousedown` the `document.getElementById("player").style.left` is a string — like `"-1px"` — that isn't interpreted as falsy (won't be coerced into `0`). You can get around that by using `parseInt()` when you cache `posl`|`posr` but you have to provide a fallback of 0 because `parseInt("")` returns `NaN`…

You can work around that like so (with similar changes when you get `posr`):

```
var posl = parseInt( document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10 ) || 0;
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("player");

function OnButtonDownl(button) {
  //var posl = document.getElementById("player").style.left;
  var posl = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10) || 0;
  window.idl = setInterval(framel, 5);

  function framel() {
    posl--;
    elem.style.left = posl + 'px';
  }
}

function OnButtonUpl(button) {
  clearInterval(idl);
}

var elem = document.getElementById("player");

function OnButtonDownr(button) {
  //var posr = document.getElementById("player").style.left;
  var posr = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left, 10) || 0;
  window.idr = setInterval(framer, 5);

  function framer() {
    posr++;
    elem.style.left = posr + 'px';
  }
}

function OnButtonUpr(button) {
  clearInterval(idr);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;// changed for example only
  height: 100vh;// changed for example only
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#player {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id='player' src='//placekitten.com/102/102' />
<div class='buttons'>
  <button id='moveleft' onmousedown="OnButtonDownl (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpl (this)">Left</button>
  <button id='moveright' onmousedown="OnButtonDownr (this)" onmouseup="OnButtonUpr (this)">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is good practice to put your script tag inside your html tags:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>...</body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='move.js'></script>
</html>
```

Done that check this solution:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'></head>
<body>
    <img id='player' src='https://placeimg.com/54/45/any' style='height:64px;'></img>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <button id='moveleft' onmousedown="OnButtonDown('left')" onmouseup="OnButtonUp()"><--</button>
        <button id='moveright' onmousedown="OnButtonDown('right')" onmouseup="OnButtonUp()">--></button>
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='move.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And js:

```
var nIntervId;
var b;
var elem = document.getElementById("player");

var posl = document.getElementById("player").style.left;

function OnButtonDown(button) {
b = button;
nIntervId = setInterval(frame, 5);
}

function frame() {
  if(b==='left'){
    posl--;
    elem.style.left = posl + 'px';}
  else{
    posl++;
    elem.style.left = posl + 'px';
  }
}

function OnButtonUp() {
    clearInterval(nIntervId);
}
```

http://output.jsbin.com/varaseheru/

Answer (score 0):

I was rewrite your code and it work (for me).

```
function Move(elem){
    this.interval;

    var posr = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("player")).left);

    this.handleEvent = function(event) {
      switch (event.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
            this.interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (event.target.id == 'moveright') {
                    posr++;
                } else if (event.target.id == 'moveleft'){
                    posr--;
                }
                document.getElementById("player").style.left = posr + 'px';

            },5);
            break;
        case 'mouseup':
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            break;
      }
  }
  elem.addEventListener('mousedown', this,  false);
  elem.addEventListener('mouseup', this,  false);

}

var button_right = document.getElementById("moveright");
var button_left = document.getElementById("moveleft");

Move(button_right);
Move(button_left);
```

And in html you can remove js event listeners (this need only id).